# deleting model when foreignkey is deleted in django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views

So, I have a model something like this

```
class Blog(models.Model):
      id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
      posted_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)

      def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
            # to do before delete
            super().delete(*args, **kwargs)
```

I want to delete all Blog objects related to User when the User is deleted.
It is working but its deleting object without calling overridden delete function.
I want to delete the model through the overridden delete function coz i have something to do before actually deleting the object. If it is not possible, do suggest any other way to do it.

Comment: As per Official doc https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#overriding-model-methods which mentions:::::::::::::: Overridden model methods are not called on bulk operations

Note that the delete() method for an object is not necessarily called when deleting objects in bulk using a QuerySet or as a result of a cascading delete. To ensure customized delete logic gets executed, you can use pre_delete and/or post_delete signals.

Unfortunately, there isn’t a workaround when creating or updating objects in bulk, since none of save(), pre_save, and post_save are called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should still be possible with `pre_delete` signal:

```
@receiver(pre_delete, sender=Blog)
def my_pre_delete_process_for_blog(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    ...
```

From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/models/#overriding-model-methods):

> Note that the delete() method for an object is not necessarily called when deleting objects in bulk using a QuerySet or as a result of a cascading delete. **To ensure customized delete logic gets executed, you can use pre_delete and/or post_delete signals.**